# Multiple drag line in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm coding a graph base on this example (http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434), but with 2 lines. My current problem is:

In my first line (blue), it's possible to drag the line correctly, when I click in a circle point and move the mouse, the line is drawing correctly.

In the second line(red), I can click in the circle point and move it, but the line doesn't change.

My code:

https://jsfiddle.net/nattanlucena/oeybge1s/1/

I noticed the error on line 181, in this piece of code:

```
var lines = this.svg.select("path").attr("d", this.line_max_weight(this.points_max_weight));
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The difference between the lines can be seen on the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcmpnia0q85f530/Captura%20de%20tela%20de%202017-02-28%2017%3A45%3A26.png?dl=0

Comment: Your red line is created on `this.svg` but blue line is created inside svg element appended in line 124 to `this.svg`.

Comment: Hi @barbsan, I changed my code and the red line is drawn correctly now, but when I zoom the yAxis, the red line is not included in the zoom: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfwk9bpe48tm08e/Captura%20de%20tela%20de%202017-03-01%2015%3A43%3A39.png?dl=0